# Multiple instances of Window Error Reporting pointing at Geolocation.dll

Tags: windows-10, windows-error-reporting

Recently after fall creator update, my computer experienced high CPU occasionally because of multiple instances of wermgr.exe (Windows Error Reporting) are running in the background.

Apparently when I check the event logs, all of them shared the similar log file pointing towards  Geolocation.dll.

May I know how to solve this issue?

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Windows Error Reporting 

  - EventID 1001 

   [ Qualifiers]  0 

   Level 4 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2017-10-23T19:06:39.613315700Z 

   EventRecordID 9675 

   Channel Application 

   Computer Shian 

   Security 


- EventData 


   0 
   WindowsNonFatalSuspectedDeadlock 
   Not available 
   0 
   2 
   Unknown 
   Geolocation.dll 
   GetGeopositionOperationImpl 
   420000 
   Windows::Devices::Geolocation::GetGeopositionOperationImpl::InitializeAndStart 




   \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER65CB.tmp.mdmp \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER701F.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_2_f2d98841ee2bcd5605336a51b671781648283_00000000_cab_40c141fa\memory.hdmp 
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_2_f2d98841ee2bcd5605336a51b671781648283_00000000_cab_40c141fa 

   0 
   b13a9adf-eb70-4de1-92c8-d6d1b312aaa7 
   4
```

Comment: You can probably get these to stop by just disabling location services for the system in the Privacy section of the Settings app, provided of course that you don't have anything on the system that uses them.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn It doesn't help.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn  The problem comes back few days later

Comment: @KuKKi Disabling Windows Error Reporting Service in `services.msc` solved the issue for me. However, I'd prefer other way, so I turned it back on as well as removed all the permissions from Geolocation.dll as per Zas' answer. So far so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently got this problem myself and from the error report saw it was about `system32\Geolocation.dll` loaded into `explorer.exe`.

To fix it you can deny system access to this file and it will not be executed anymore. If you have trouble using your PC to do these steps then enter safe mode on your Windows and perform them there.

Open `C:\windows\system32\`, find and open properties of `Geolocation.dll`. Go to security tab and at the bottom click `Advanced`

[Security preferences image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhaZY.png)

In the next window it should say TrustedInstaller is the owner of this file, we need to change it to be able to deny access. Click on `Change` at the top

[Advanced image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JxWZ.png)

Type your Windows login username in the box that appears and `Check names`. This should make you the owner of this file.

Now go back to the first window with security options for Geolocation.dll. Now click `Edit` to change it's permissions. Go through every permission and remove all check marks. This includes all system packages, TrustedInstaller and even yourself. Don't worry, permissions can be added back later if you wish to.

[Permissions removed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq2jQ.png)

Now restart `explorer.exe` in task manager or reboot windows to apply these changes. `explorer.exe` should no longer be able to load `Geolocation.dll` and thus will not produce infinite error messages.

Comment: I have followed your steps and removed every single permission for  Geolocation.dll.  Will give it a few days to check if the problem comes back. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Removing your user's read & execute seems to cause a crash when opening settings.